# render html from email.body object

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid

I am using griddler and sendgrid to receive emails into my rails app but when I render email.body I only get the text in the email and not the actual html styled email. I use `<%= raw post.body %>` and still get the same thing. Any ideas on how I can have an email body render its html version as if you would see it in Gmail or Yahoo instead of stripping it out and rendering only the text in the email. I am using Rails 4, Sendgrid, and Griddler Gem.

My email_processor.rb file to process emails:

```
class EmailProcessor
  def self.process(email)
  Post.create!({ body: email.body, email: email.from })
  end
end
```

index.html.rb

```
<h1>Posts</h1>

<% if @posts.count > 0 %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <blockquote>
      <p><%= raw post.body %></p>
      <small><%= post.email %></small>
    </blockquote>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p><em>Oops, doesn't look like there are any posts yet.</em></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `email.body`, you most likely should be calling `email.raw_html`. If this doesn't work, their documentation for Griddler suggests

> **Adapters**
>
> Griddler::Email expects certain parameters to be in place for proper parsing to occur. When writing an adapter, ensure that the
>   normalized_params method of your adapter returns a hash with these
>   keys:
>
> :html The html body of the email, nil or empty string if not present

Comment: Kobaltz I did try email.raw_html and it works when I embed the actual raw html in the email body, but when I copy and paste the email body in a new email and send it to the parser it does not work.

Comment: Is the new email that is not working raw text? You could do a check `email.raw_html.present? ? body = email.raw_html : body = email.body`

Comment: I think when I cut and paste the content of the email even though it is formatted correctly it removes the html and pastes it as raw text as you have suggested.

Comment: Either that or your new email's format is raw which is why it isn't preserving the HTML. The `raw_html` returns `nil` because the email it is receiving truly is `nil` as far as HTML goes. I would put in a check to make sure that you're capturing raw email bodies if the HTML body is nil.